# Oracle trigger error ORA-04091

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, database-trigger

I get an error (ORA-04091: table DBPROJEKT_AKTIENDEPOT.AKTIE is mutating, trigger/function may not see it) when executing my trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Aktien_Bilanz_Berechnung
AFTER 
INSERT OR UPDATE OF  TAGESKURS
OR INSERT OR UPDATE OF  WERT_BEIM_EINKAUF
ON AKTIE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
bfr number;
Begin
bfr := :new.TAGESKURS - :new.WERT_BEIM_EINKAUF;
UPDATE AKTIE
SET BILANZ = TAGESKURS - WERT_BEIM_EINKAUF;
IF bfr < -50
THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ACHTUNG: The value (Nr: '||:new.AKTIEN_NR||') is very low!');
END IF;
END;
```

I want to check the value "BILANZ" after calculating it, wether it is under -50.
Do you have any idea why this error is thrown?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues here:

1. Oracle does not allow you to perform a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE against a table within a row trigger defined on that table or any code called from such a trigger, which is why an error occurred at run time. There are ways to work around this - for example, you can read my answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489951/oracle-trigger-after-insert-or-delete) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917291/pl-sql-trigger-gets-a-mutating-table-error) - but in general you will have to avoid accessing the table on which a row trigger is defined from within the trigger.
2. The calculation which is being performed in this trigger is what is referred to as **business logic** and should not be performed in a trigger. Putting logic such as this in a trigger, no matter how convenient it may seem to be, will end up being very confusing to anyone who has to maintain this code because the value of `BILANZ` is changed where someone who is reading the application code's `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement can't see it. This calculation should be performed in the `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement, not in a trigger. It considered good practice to define a procedure to perform INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operations on a table so that all such calculations can be captured in one place, instead of being spread out throughout your code base.
3. Within a BEFORE ROW trigger you **can** modify the values of the fields in the `:NEW` row variable to change values before they're written to the database. There are times that this is acceptable, such as when setting columns which track when and by whom a row was last changed, but in general it's considered a bad idea.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

You are modifying the table with the trigger.  Use a `before update` trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Aktien_Bilanz_Berechnung
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF TAGESKURS OR INSERT OR UPDATE OF  WERT_BEIM_EINKAUF
ON AKTIE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    v_bfr number;
BEGIN
    v_bfr := :new.TAGESKURS - :new.WERT_BEIM_EINKAUF;
    :new.BILANZ := v_bfr;
    IF v_bfr < -50 THEN
      Raise_Application_Error(-20456,'ACHTUNG: The value (Nr: '|| :new.AKTIEN_NR || ') is very low!');
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I replaced `dbms_output.put_line` with `Raise_Application_Error` so that the error can be seen from everywhere, even from an application. Got rid of useless `dual`. +1

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan . . . Those are fine.  For some reason, I'm in the habit of using `into` when I assign values into columns in triggers in Oracle.  Don't know why.  It might be an archaic habit.