# Oracle Trigger error - ORA-04091: table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

Tags: oracle, triggers, ora-04091

I need to write a trigger, if a particular field value is changed (say employee type from salary to hourly or hourly to salary) then the the record id value need to be updated.

Note: for me old_clock will maintain the id without prefix S or H

example of id: S222222 or H3333333

clock: 222222 or 333333

I am getting the error

One error saving changes to table "USERS":

Row 1: ORA-04091: table USERS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

ORA-06512: at "TRIGGER_UPDATE_USERS_ID", line 20

ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'TRIGGER_UPDATE_USERS_ID'

CODE:

````
```create or replace TRIGGER "TRIGGER_UPDATE_USERS_ID" 

AFTER UPDATE OF

empl_type

ON USERS

FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE



new_empl_type varchar(5);

old_empl_type varchar(5);

old_pw_clock varchar(10);







BEGIN

new_empl_type := :NEW.empl_type;

old_empl_type := :OLD.empl_type;

old_clock := :OLD.clock;





if 

old_empl_type ='S' and new_empl_type ='H' 

then

 UPDATE USERS set id = 'H'||old_clock 

 where id = 'S222222';

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('updated with new id prefix to Z '|| new_empl_type);

elsif 

old_empl_type ='H' and new_empl_type ='S' 

then

 UPDATE USERS set id = 'S'||old_clock

 where id = 'H274952';

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('updated with new id prefix to M '|| new_empl_type);

end if;

END;```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle trigger error ORA-04091](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50966543/oracle-trigger-error-ora-04091)

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify - or even reference - the table to which the trigger is attached. You can only modify the fields in the row being updated, something like this:

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRIGGER_UPDATE_USERS_ID
BEFORE UPDATE OF
empl_type
ON USERS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
if :old.empl_type ='S' and :new.empl_type ='H' 
then
   :new.id = 'H'||:old.clock;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('updated with new id prefix to Z '|| :new.empl_type);
elsif old.empl_type ='H' and :new.empl_type ='S' 
then
    :new.id = 'S'||:old.clock
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('updated with new id prefix to M '|| :new.empl_type);
end if;
END;
/
```

While you *could* technically create an autonomous transaction within the trigger, it is inadvisable in this case because it would certainly lead to corrupted data if the original transaction on USERS failed.

Comment: :new.id = 'H'||:old.clock;  this line of code is it updating only for that row? hopefully do not corrupt other rows , how does it know which row to update... (sorry I am a beginner in PL/SQL)

Comment: It will only update the current row, because that is the scope of the trigger: `FOR EACH ROW`.

Comment: I am getting the error Error report -
ORA-04084: cannot change NEW values for this trigger type
04084. 00000 -  "cannot change NEW values for this trigger type"
*Cause:    New trigger variables can only be changed in before row
           insert or update triggers.
*Action:   Change the trigger type or remove the variable reference.

Comment: OK I solved the problem by changing the Trigger defenited to "BEFORE UPDATE" instead of "AFTER UPDATE" which solved the issues.